# how to show errors in JS Alert

Tags: magento2, forms, frontend-error

I have phtml form, whenever i get any error it shows a page like this  [image]

i want to show these type of errors like this [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your module controller

```
try {
            //Your program logic

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage("Your error message{$e->getMessage()}.");
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
   }
```

Comment: Hi Ali, you can accept the answer if it is correct